# Migration paths for off-topic questions

Tags: feature-request, migration

Now that we're out of beta, will we get access to the full set of stackexchange sites for migrations ?

Answer (score 2):

To give some insight into why this probably isn't needed (at least right now): **we have very few migrations, and they are “all over the place”**. Among 20 questions migrated (away from Academia) for the last 3 months, the most common target was [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), and it accounted for only 3 migrations. Then we have our own Meta site (2), then all other sites have had only one (successful) migration.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what power users get to see. I know moderators have the ability to migrate anywhere on SE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is planned. I know I put in a [feature request for this a long time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration/110996#110996), but it was closed as [status-declined](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined). So, I'm thinking not.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is very obvious, each migration path is typically discussed separately. SE also requires in most cases that there is already a bit of a history of successful mod migrations to that specific site before enabling a path for community migrations.

So I'd start by looking at the migration statistics, I think only mods can see those, and see if there are any sites where a migration path might be useful. Then you can post a feature request and ask someone from SE to take a look at it.